# RethinkDB Thinky - rows within 1 hour

Tags: rethinkdb, thinky

```
r.db('dbname').table('urls').filter(function(url) {
  return url("expires_at").date().eq(r.now().date())
    .and(url("expires_at").hours().eq(r.now().hours().sub(1)))
});
```

I am trying to write the equivalent query using thinky ORM for node.js

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never worked with Thinky, but according to docs, you should create model and make query on it.

1) Create model. I don't know what documents you are storing in Rethink. But something like this:

```
var thinky = require('thinky')();
var type   = thinky.type;

// Create a model
var Urls = thinky.createModel("urls", {
  id: String,
  expires_at: Date
  // another fields if needed
});
```

2) Query:

Don't know actual syntaxes for filter in Thinky, but somehting like this:

```
Urls.filter(function(url) {
     return url("expires_at").date().eq(r.now().date())
           .and(url("expires_at").hours().eq(r.now().hours().sub(1)))
}).then(function(result) {
     // result is an array of instances of `Urls `
});
```

Comment: thanks. #2 did the trick. I didn't see that in the docs - can you link to it?

Comment: @TResudek Filter? Here is simple sample https://thinky.io/documentation/api/thinky/#r